# limit of $\cos x ^{\tan x}$

Tags: limits

As far as I know, $0^\infty$ is not an indefinite form and it goes to zero. Then the limit of $(\cos x)^{\tan x}$ when $x$ goes to $\pi/2 - $ should equal $0$.

But after log transformation, its limit is $\infty$. I am not sure which one is correct, zero or infinity?

Thanks for your help.

I slightly changed the question. I realized that $x$ goes to $\pi/2 - $ (left hand limit) in the original question.

Comment: Limit doesn't exist, but we can consider unilateral limits. If $x\to\pi/2^{-}$ then $(\cos x)^{\tan x}\to 0$. On the other hand, if $x\to\pi/2^{+}$ then $(\cos x)^{\tan x}$ takes complex values.

Comment: What did you get from the log transformation? $\log((\cos x)^{\tan x}) = \tan x \log(\cos x)$, which isn't an indeterminate form either. $\tan x$ goes to $\infty$ and $\log(\cos x)$ goes to $-\infty$ (taking left-sided limits). Since the logarithm of the thing goes to $-\infty$, the thing goes to $0$, as expected.

Comment: oh.. you're right. since the log of the thing is -infinity, the thing goes to zero. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are functions such that as $x \to a$, $f(x) \to 0$ and $g(x) \to \infty$, and consider $h(x) = f(x)^{g(x)}$.  We know that
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \ln h(x) = \lim_{x \to a} g(x) \ln f(x) = -\infty,
$$
Thus,
$$
\lim_{x \to a} h(x) = 0.
$$